# Full instant build cost?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How many gems does one need to build a village in Clash of Clans from 0 to full, instantly (using gems to finish, have the resources and whatever it needs) and how much would that cost in real money?

Answer (score 10):

According to the Clash of Clans wiki the total cost of upgrading everything is 1,688,882 gems which works out to be $12,068.77. Now that is assuming you have 2,860d 5h 7m to spare because the cost estimate is for build only and does not take into account speeding any of the build times up.

Check out the link here for an explanation of how time plays into the mix as well as how much each level costs in both resources/gems/real money.

http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Cumulative_Costs

Comment: Is it 2860 days for 5 builders?

Comment: No with five from the start its just under 600 days.

Answer (score 4):

with speeding everything up, you will max out with 19,602.87 U.S. Dollars. That's about as much a PE Teacher makes annually in Los Altos, CA. The most expensive area in the U.S. Well, I'm posting this in July 2015 and supercell has made a lot of expensive updates including dark spells so my calculations are based on sources from 2014. Now it's about 22,000 Dollars